# git merge two branch from one commit up to HEAD

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 branches -> A & B

A 20 commits ahead than B.

I want merge last 3 commits of A into B and I know if I execute command `git merge d8329f` for example, it'll merge all commits from up to the given SHA commit (not to end).

is there anything in git like `git merge d8329f fdf4fc3` to merge just commits which are between (including the two given commits) these two commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git cherry-pick <commit>`.

```
$ git checkout A
# copy the last 3 commit sha somewhere else 

$ git checkout B 
$ git cherry-pick <commit1> <commit2> <commit2>

# cherry pick a range of commits
$ git cherry-pick <from-sha>^..<to-sha>
```

**Note:** `^` at `from-sha` because first shat is not included. Here, "`<from-sha>^`" denotes the first parent of `"<from-sha>"`;

[More cherry-pick example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples)

Comment: @Seyed it also takes an unbounded list of params, so you can do `git cherry-pick <commit1> <commit2> <commit3>`

Comment: cherry-pick just get one commit, doesn't it?

Comment: @jbu if there are more than 3 commits, (think about 100 commits between 2 specific commits), I can't get their SHA one by one, it takes too much

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan: `git cherry-pick d8329f..fdf4fc3`